# Can't seem to select from drop down menu - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, frame, webdriverwait

As titled, seems like I just can't select the drop down menu from this website no matter what.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://assessing.nashuanh.gov/search.asp')

time.sleep(1)

select=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cboSearchType"]'))
select.select_by_value('2')
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to handdle the frames in your page. Also looks like there is no value `2` inside this dropdown, so you have to pass a valid value.

```py
driver.switch_to.frame("middle")

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cboSearchType"]'))
select.select_by_value('Parcel')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<option>` element with value/text as **Owner** within the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) is within an `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `select_by_value()`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://assessing.nashuanh.gov/search.asp')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='middle']")))
    Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#cboSearchType")))).select_by_value("Owner")
    ```
  - Using `XPATH` and `select_by_visible_text()`:

    ```
    driver.get('https://assessing.nashuanh.gov/search.asp')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='middle']")))
    Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='cboSearchType']")))).select_by_visible_text("Owner")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: nashuanh]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)